# Is it possible to disable splash screen for an install4j'd Java app at runtime?

Tags: java, splash-screen, install4j, headless

I have a Java application installed with install4j.  In some test environments, it is useful to have it launch in a headless environment.  However, currently this throws:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:431)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at com.install4j.runtime.splashscreen.JavaSplashScreen.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.splashscreen.JavaSplashController.show(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.SplashEngine.showSplashScreen(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

As the splash screen is the only part of the program that requires a display, it would be great if this can be disabled using a command line switch, or at the least some code within the program itself (this would seem an unlikely option as this exception is thrown before my code runs).  Is there such an option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such runtime option in install4j, you would have to configure a separate command line launcher without a splash screen.